# Where is the implementation of GTK_IS_ROOT in gtk4?

Tags: gtk

Where is the implementation of that function?

is a macro function

I searched the source code but couldn't find it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`GTK_IS_ROOT()` is defined by the `G_DECLARE_INTERFACE (GtkRoot, gtk_root, GTK, ROOT, GtkWidget)` at https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gtk/-/blob/main/gtk/gtkroot.h#L35 macro. This is a GObject macro and GTK uses GObject extensively.

Basically: when writing GObject classes or interfaces, you need to write quite a bit of boilerplace to implement inheritance right, ideally in a way that helps with ABI stability. GObject provides macros that make it easier for you: [`G_DECLARE_FINAL_TYPE()`](https://docs.gtk.org/gobject/func.DECLARE_FINAL_TYPE.html), [`G_DECLARE_DERIVABLE_TYPE()`](https://docs.gtk.org/gobject/func.DECLARE_DERIVABLE_TYPE.html) and [`G_DECLARE_INTERFACE()`](https://docs.gtk.org/gobject/func.DECLARE_INTERFACE.html) are macros that respectively do the declaration for a final class (which can't be subclassed), a derivable class, and an interface.

One of the things that you often want to do with runtime inheritance, is to perform certain checks related to the type of a certain parameter or variable. The aforementioned macros help out with that by generating some extra macros to implement such functionality.

Given a namespace `Xxx` (for example `Gtk`) and a type name `Yyy` (for example `Root`) it will provide an `XXX_IS_YYY(var)` macro to check if the given variable `var` is truly an instance of the class (i.e. it implements the `instanceof()` operator you might know of other languages)

Comment: Good! Thank you!

Comment: Glad I could help! Please accept the answer if it did answer your question :-)